# Is there a way to control the order of properties in JSON objects?

Tags: c#, .net, partial-classes

I'm using Entity Framework Core, and the generated class has its own properties, i.e.

**DataModel.Agent.cs**

```
public partial class Agent {

    public virtual decimal Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

But I need other properties, so I declare them in another file:

**Agent.cs**

```
public partial class Agent
{
    [NotMapped]
    public dynamic Custom { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that Agent.cs is compiled before DataModel.Agent.cs, so the compiler generates properties in this order: Custom, Id, Name, and the resulting JSON is weird.

I want it to be: Id, Name, Custom. In other words, I always want the DataModel class to come first.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the only objective is to make the JSON prettier by always putting the Id first, which is a very common pattern. This has absolutely no impact on how the application works.

Is there a way to force the compiler to always compile one of the files first?

Comment: This is true, JSON property order is NOT supposed to be counted on.

Comment: Json objects are serialized as dictionaries. Dictionary keys have no inherent order

Comment: What do you mean "the resulting JSON is weird"? Objects are serialized as dictionaries in JSON and have no inherent order. A dictionary with ID, Name, Custom is *equivalent* to another one with ID, Custom, Name if they have the same values

Comment: I'm using ASP.Net Core, which uses Json.Net, and it serializes using the same order as the declaration of the properties. By weird I mean that I always want Id to be the first field on the JSON, which is a pretty common approach, but it's not working that way.

Also, it's only to make the JSON prettier, it has absolutely no impact on how the application works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you really shouldn't count on JSON property order BUT if using json.net

```
public class Account
 {
 public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

 // appear last
 [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
 public bool Deleted { get; set; }

 [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
  public DateTime DeletedDate { get; set; }

  public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

  // appear first
  [JsonProperty(Order = -2)]
  public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, which is ordering the whole file, but it did solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this and VS may end up reordering them automatically but try changing the order of the files inside your .csproj files ItemGroup that contains all the compile tags, I believe Build will just read them from the csproj in the order they are in. For .Net file compilation order is irrelevant outside of project order for references.

Comment: The key to understanding this is this: "MSBuild project file standard offers you a declarative language used to formulate build rules, not imperative" - ie order does not matter at all.